# How to get all intermediary redirects using Symfony HttpClient

Tags: symfony

How to get the url of all redirects using HttpClient?

Here is an example:

1. http://example.com/page 301 redirects to:
2. http://www.example.com/page 302 redirects to:
3. http://www.example.com/page/

```
$response = $this->httpClient->request('GET', 'http://example.com/page');
$content = $response->getContent(false);    
$ary = $response->getInfo();
```

Only in the '[debug]' part of the getInfo I can see:

```
Issue another request to this URL: 'http://www.example.com/page'
...
Issue another request to this URL: 'http://www.example.com/page/'
```

Is there a way to retrieve the URLs of the redirects without parsing the debug text?

Answer (score 2):

you can intercept redirects by setting the max_redirects parameter:

```
try {
    $this->httpClient->request('GET', 'http://example.com/page', ['max_redirects' => 0])->getContent();
    // not redirected
} catch (RedirectionException $e) {
    $redirectUrl = $e->getResponse()->getInfo()['redirect_url'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks @COil, yep, I can wrap your code in a `foreach` loop. Inside each cycle fetching the new `redirect_url`. Will use this approach if there are no elegant (built-in) ways of getting an array of all `redirect_url`s

Comment: No, I don't think the httpl-client has something "out of the box" to do it. Way be you can do a recursive call? Perhaps, it's not the right tool to do this. But Guzzle allows to this with the history plugin: https://guzzle3.readthedocs.io/http-client/http-redirects.html#redirect-history

Comment: Yep, initially I planned to use Guzzle, a great library! But since I use Symfony and there is already the HttpClient component, why adding new external libraries to the app?

Comment: The http-client is young, it may not have all the features that guzzle provides. But if you can do it with properly with the Symfony http client it's better. Feel free to share your code when it's finished. ;)